# Get url from firefox 8 not working anymore

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, firefox, automation

I have a windows applicaiton c# catching the url of a running firefox instance.
I have always used "MozillaContentWindow" to get firefox URL but i dont understand why it dont work anymore.

```
string s = GetUrlFromBrowsersWithIdentifier("MozillaContentWindow", foreGround);

public string GetUrlFromBrowsersWithIdentifier(string identifier, int foreground)
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(foreground);
            var aeBrowser = AutomationElement.FromHandle(ptr);
            return aeBrowser == null ? "" : GetURLfromBrowser(aeBrowser, identifier);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    string GetURLfromBrowser(AutomationElement rootElement, string identifier)
    {
        try
        {

            Condition condition1 = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsContentElementProperty, true);

            Condition condition2 = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, identifier);

            var walker = new TreeWalker(new AndCondition(condition1, condition2));

            var elementNode = walker.GetFirstChild(rootElement);

            if (elementNode != null)
            {
                var p = elementNode.GetSupportedPatterns();

                if (p.Any(autop => autop.ProgrammaticName.Equals("ValuePatternIdentifiers.Pattern")))
                {
                    var valuePattern = elementNode.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;

                    if (valuePattern != null)
                        return (valuePattern.Current.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        }

        return "";

    }
```

Now when it enters "walker.GetFirstChild(rootElement);" it just stops there. I cant figure out why. This only happend on latest version of firefox.

Did they change the name of the value bar containing the url?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see anywhere is this code where you are using "WWW_GetWindowInfo"

Comment: @Alastair i am sorry, it should be "MozillaContentWindow", i just tried it on older firefox version and it worked, but not the latest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using MozillaWindowContentClass for newer versions.